# Same relation for two fields in one data type

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql

can I write something like this:

```
type User {
 primaryStory: Story! @relation(name: "userStory")
 secondaryStories: [Story] @relation(name: "userStory")
}
type Story {
 user: User! @relation(name: "userStory")
}
```

Basically what I want is to have a single relation name for both primary story and secondary stories.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. With the name specified in an ambiguous way it is not clear what the userStory relates to.

You could either have 2 different relation names, or have a construct like the following and filter accordingly:

```
type User {
 stories: Story! @relation(name: "userStories")
}
type Story {
 author: User! @relation(name: "userStories")
 isPrimary: Boolean! 
}
```